# ofstream doesn't write buffer to file

Tags: c++, ofstream

I'm trying to write the contents of buf pointer to the file created by ofstream.

For some reason the file is empty, however the contents of buf is never empty...  What am I doing wrong?

```
void DLog::Log(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list varptr;

    va_start(varptr, fmt);

    int n = ::_vscprintf(fmt, varptr);
    char *buf = new char[n + 1];
    ::vsprintf(buf, fmt, varptr);

    va_end(varptr);

    if (!m_filename.empty())
    {

        std::ofstream ofstr(m_filename.c_str(), ios::out);

        ofstr << *buf; // contents of *buf are NEVER empty, however nothing is in file??

        ofstr.close();
    }


    delete [] buf;
}
```

Comment: I think we'd need to see the calling code too, maybe you can strip this down to a compilable example? Also, don't use manual allocation like that. :) Change your `buf` stuff to `std::vector<char> buf(n + 1);` and `::vsprintf(&buf[0], fmt, varptr);` and for outputting, `std::copy(buf.begin(), buf.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(ofstr))`. And of course, no need to `delete []` anymore. Also, you don't need to call `ofstr.close()`, the destructor does that anyway.

Comment: have you checked permissions on the log file?

Comment: @GMan: Wouldn't `std::string` fit the need even more than `std::vector<char>` ?

Comment: @GMan: thanks for the tips, so the copy is done to write to the ofstream?

Comment: @ereOn: Practically, yes, technically no. `std::string` doesn't currently guarantee that elements be stored contiguously like `std::vector`, so you can't use `&str[0]` to get the array. (Because there doesn't have to be one.) That said, you'd be hard-pressed to find an implementation where it's not just an array. But I still prefer the guaranteed solution. @Tony: Yes, it'll copy from `buf.begin()` to `buf.end()`, outputting to the `ostream_iterator`. That's just a utility iterator that makes `*iter = x` output `x` to the stream. So it copies each character in `buf` to `ofstr`.

Comment: GMAN: I'll take your answer as accepted; if you place it in an answer!

Comment: @Tony: Did that fix the problem? Even if you decide to go with my code (I hope you do!), it would be better if someone like @ereOn who tried to help you with your already existent code got the accepted answer, assuming his suggestions did in fact work.

Comment: GMan: used your code and it works!!! :)  That's why I wanted to use your answer as accepted.  I have this slight feeling your use of vectors is better then my char pointer.

Comment: @Tony: I'll add it as an answer, but do try ereOn's answer and see if that would have fixed it. If so, accept his.

Comment: @GMan: I thought in the c++0x spec that std:string was now guaranteed to be contiguous (see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#530), and as you say most implementations do that already.

Comment: @graham: Indeed, in C++0x elements must be contiguous. I said "currently", though, as in C++03. C++0x isn't quite yet standard. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many problems can be solved by getting rid of the hairy stuff, like manual allocation management.

Never use `new T[N]` in your code: instead use `std::vector<T> v(N);`. Simply this alone might solve your problem, because the pointer stuff isn't in the way:

```
void DLog::Log(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list varptr;
    va_start(varptr, fmt);

    int n = ::_vscprintf(fmt, varptr);
    std::vector<char> buf(n + 1);

    ::vsprintf(&buf[0], fmt, varptr);

    va_end(varptr);

    if (!m_filename.empty())
    {
        std::ofstream ofstr(m_filename.c_str(), ios::out);
        if (!ofstr) 
        {
            // didn't open, do some error reporting here
        }

        // copy each character to the stream
        std::copy(buf.begin(), buf.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(ofstr));

        // no need to close, it's done automatically
    }

    // no need to remember to delete
}
```

Much easier to read and maintain. Note even better would be a `std::string buf(n + 1);`, then you could just do `ofstr << buf;`. Sadly, `std::string` isn't currently required to store its elements contiguously, like `std::vector`. This means the line with `&buf[0]` isn't guaranteed to work. That said, I doubt you'll find an implementation where it wouldn't work. Still, it's arguably better to maintain guaranteed behavior.

I do [suspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279733/ofstream-doesnt-write-buffer-to-file/3279778#3279778) the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279733/ofstream-doesnt-write-buffer-to-file/3279814#3279814) was you dereferencing the pointer, though.

Answer (score 4):

Is your stream opened before writing on it ? Could be anything from not-enough disk space to unsufficient permissions.

Also you may have an error:

```
ofstr << *buf;
```

Should be something like:

```
ofstr << buf;
```

Since `buf` is a `char*`, `*buf` gives a `char`, not a `char*`.

This is where using `std::string` instead of raw buffers/pointers makes sense ;)

Answer (score 1):

the error is in line

ofstr << *buf;

it should be

ofstr << buf;

Answer (score 1):

You need to flush the ofstream before closing it. Try `ofstr.flush();` before `ofstr.close();` I had this error some time ago when I thought that closing the stream automatically flushes it but, as it turned out, it doesn't.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should, perhaps that was a bug in your implementation. But maybe I'm wrong, I"ll look.

Comment: @GMan: Did you look into it? Do tell us if you find any thing interesting

Comment: Ah, yeah. It is indeed the case `close()` flushes the stream, and that `close()` is called by the destructor. §27.8.​1.2/3 describes the destructor of a `basic_filebuf`, and says that it calls `close()`. §27.8.​1.3/6 describes the closing procedure, which includes flushing the stream. And of course the file streams all have the same behavior as owning a `basic_filebuf` as a member, meaning when they destruct the `basic_filebuf` does, leading to the previous effects.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the ofstream is open for writing after being created.