# Convert vector<char> buf(256) to LPCSTR?

Tags: c++, vector, types

Is there a way to convert the above?

If so what is the best way?

I guess you can loop through the vector and assign to a `const char*`, but I'm not sure if that is the best way.

Comment: Any reason using a vector instead of a string ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200188/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lpcstr

Comment: @DumbCoder: see this question and the first comment of GMan for the reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279733/ofstream-doesnt-write-buffer-to-file

Comment: It's inside a variadic function, using vsprintf, don't know if strings are usable here...

Comment: Are you sure you need `LPCSTR`? The 8-bit string datatypes in Windows are obsolete and deprecated; use the UTF-16 string types like `LPCWSTR` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::string s(vec.begin(), vec.end());
// now use s.c_str()
```

I think this should be fairly safe.

Comment: maybe use the two-iterator constructor `s(vec.begin(), vec.end())` instead? Seems to be a bit more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a `std::string` instead of the `std::vector<char>` ?

I believe `std::string` is similar to `std::vector<char>` so you can use it the same way, and benefit of its additional functions.

If so, `std::string` has a method `.c_str()` that returns a null-terminated C-string (a `const char*`).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
std::string str(&myVec[0], myVec.size());
```

And then `str.c_str()` will return you a `const char *` to play with. But this is assuming that the data in the vector is null-terminated. If it is not, then there are no guarantees.

Comment: Only the constructor that doesn't take a size parameter requires the string to be null-terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the simple

```
LPCSTR str = &vec[0];
```

A vector already contains the contiguous storage that C strings require. But be careful that `vec` is already null-terminated, and that `vec` cannot be destroyed while `str` is still used. Generally `vec` can be destroyed as soon as it is not used anymore, so storing pointers into `vec` is dangerous and will lead to crashes. OTOH, passing the pointer as argument might be fine:

```
f(&vec[0]);  // f takes a LPCSTR parameter
```

Comment: Also, the memory can move around whenever more memory is reserved, so you'd have to make sure the vector isn't manipulated while the pointer exists.